# In Glenn Gould's "So you want to write a fugue", what's that instrumental part?

Tags: classical-music, fugue

I come from learning about fugues and encountered the seemingly famous "So you want to write a fugue" piece by Glenn Gould.

In the middle, there is this instumental part:

To my (rock music listening) ears, this sounds quite like the equivalent of a guitar solo in the middle of a piece, but in classical music.

Is this instrumental part intended to be some sort of joke, in the context of this specific piece? It feels so misplaced there.

Comment: I once listened to a piano transcription of this piece, and I don't remember *anything* sticking out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's a little joke. After the words "... John Sebastian must have been a very personable guy" the instrumental part starts with the first 4 bars of J S Bach's Brandenburg Concerto No 2.